# Is there a way of using the .load() method to fetch data from a page without loading all the images on that page?

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation bar which display prices of the products. I am fetching and inserting the prices using the .load() method but it is causing all the images on the referenced pages to download. Is there a way to just fetch the data without having all the images load as well?

```
$("#navigation-block1").load("/url.html .price:lt(1)" );
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample code of the response would help. If you need to stay in js with your code you could be doing something like:

```
$.get( "/url.html", function( data ) {
  //some sort of parser to extract what you need
  var price = myPriceExtractor(data);
  $("#navigation-block1").html( price );
});
```